# Initiating a call though 3rd party VoIP app on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, voip

I'd like to assign an action to a phone number displayed in my iPad app. Since there is no original Apple Phone app on the tablet, it does nothing if I use `NSURL` with a `tel:` prefix. Is there any way to figure out if there are any voip-capable apps on the user's device and start that?

Edit: the phone number is displayed in a block of text, and I'd like the user to be able to tap and call. On the iPhone it is trivial, on the iPad since there is no phone app it's a bit different.

Comment: The phone number is displayed in a block of text, and I'd like the user to be able to tap and call. On the iPhone it is trivial, on the iPad since there is no phone app it's a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

To see if your device can call the number using the phone app, check the `tel:` URL scheme:

```
canMakePhoneCalls = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+44-1234-567890"]]);
```

To see if your device has Skype, check the `callto:` URL scheme:

```
canMakeSkypePhoneCalls = ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"callto:+44-1234-567890"]]);
```